# How to show the menu bar on secondary desktops (spaces) on Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: osx-lion, mission-control

I added additional Desktops (previously known as Spaces) via Mission Control on Lion. On each additional desktop the menu bar is missing. The menu bar is only visible/accessible from the primary desktop.

What do I need to change to make the menu bar appear on all Desktop spaces?

Here's my current setup as seen through Mission Control. I have 6 Desktops, but the menu bar is only available on Desktop 1. All other desktops have no menu bar, and thus running an application on Desktops 2-6 is more or less useless right now. I want these Desktops to work like the Spaces in Snow Leopard.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure these are additional desktops, and not full-screen applications? The latter contain a hidden menu bar only.

Comment: Could yu maybe upload a screenshot otherwise?

Comment: This feature is unavaiable in Lion (or any OSX for that matter). An alternative solution that may partially solve your problem is this: Navigate to System Preferences/Displays then, you can click and drag the menubar from one screen to the other in the Display window. This will effectively change your primary display to where ever you drag the menubar, but stretching or repeating the menu bar acrross multiple displays isnt possible.

Comment: I don't think this is the user's issue. This isn't about external additional screens (as in hardware), but virtual desktops via Mission Control (formerly "Spaces")

Comment: My question is about showing the menu bar on every virtual desktop (spaces), it isn't about spanning multiple monitors.

Comment: Added a screenshot. Not sure if that helps, I tried to describe the issue. On Desktop 4 I have Xcode running, and not fullscreen. But no menu bar, which makes it pretty useless to put applications on other desktops.

Comment: Ok, I guess I didn't read into it enough. Lion really handicapped OSX's ability to use Spaces, and the problem you are describing doesn't have a solution. You could downgrade to SL and that would allow you to use Spaces like you want, where you are creating virtual desktops and not full screen apps. (your issue is common and many people downgrade because of it)

Comment: Oh sh … certainly not going to downgrade, I'd rather hope Apple is coming to sense with Mission Control. Still, this is seriously limiting. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to have been an intermittent (?) bug. I simply removed all desktops I had created, and then re-added new desktops. Every new one I added using the exact same method as before (click on the + in Mission Control's upper right corner) now has the menu bar.